# Django include tag isn't working

Tags: django, include

I'm trying to make my page in seperate parts - and one of them goes for the top menu, so far, however, I can't figure out how to include the top menu template in the rest of the pages. `{% include "top_menu.html" %}` for some reason doesn't work, do I have to update my views or smthn for it to take effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is `top_menu.html` relative to the `templates/` directory ?

Comment: well it's inside the templates directory, if that's what you ment

Comment: Please type up the general folder/file structure in templates. Maybe "top_menu.html" is nested in some folders?

Comment: Nope, it's in the root templates directory. I only have 3 files in it and base.html works through `{% extend "base.html" %}`, but top_menu.html - doesn't.

Comment: You don't have to change anything else - don't even need to restart Django... What's the error message? Looks to me like a typo in the name or path like Xeen said.

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue and have seen quite a few other similar posts. In my case the issue was caused by my outer template having `{% load staticfiles %}` which was also needed by the included file.

The fix was to repeat `{% load staticfiles %}` inside the included file. The problem was made difficult by Django not giving an error message when it failed to load the include file, so there weren't any clues.

Comment: Also applies if you're loading anything other then staticfiles, i.e. custom template tags.

Comment: Same issue, but adding `{% load staticfiles %}` doesn't fix it. Maybe it's because it's a page loaded from an iframe?

Comment: In my case it was a load issue. Sometimes Django have some problems with the browser. So, delete change the name of the template of the include (avoiding using "_" and same name of other templates. delete the include and place it closer to the html code far from the ```{% block content %}``` tag. In addition, add again a new include tag and see whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the exact same problem. Try putting the include tags in the body tag of html.

```
<body>
{% include "top_menu.html" %}
 .
 .
</body>
```

And keep the load static tag outside the html. Put it at the top of the code outside html.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template file in templates/<app_name>/like and move your topmenu.html to the same folder. Then in the template add:

```
{% include 'templates/topmenu.html' %}
```

Often people try to include in their template files which contain code blocks, like content block for example. If you do that, Django will not render your included template or give any error.